# Read file details (not language dependent)

Tags: c#

In C#, I would like to read file details from a specific file.
I've found an interesting thread: [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)

it uses a call to the GetDetailsOf() method on the folder shell object included in shell32.dll.
It works fine but I have an issue: According to the Operating System language, the header string is never the same...('Name' for the filename property on an english Windows, 'Nom' on a french Windows).
So, it's not easy to retrieve specific values with the name of the property as it changes according to the language...
Is there a way to handle this easily?

Answer (score 0):

Some properties are available through the FileInfo object. For example, if you want the creation time of the file you can do:

```
Fileinfo myFileInfo = new Fileinfo(@"C:\path\to\file");
DateTime ftime = myFileInfo.CreationTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class not enough for your needs ?

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo("fileName");
var name = info.Name;
var creationTime = info.CreationTime;
// etc ...
```

If not, tell more about which properties you'd like to read from your file.

---

**Update to my answer :**

I don't know about a library that would allow to read *any* type of document properties'

But here are a few ways for the formats you said,

**PDF** :

[Extracting Additional Metadata from a PDF using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928441/extracting-additional-metadata-from-a-pdf-using-itextsharp)

[Read/Modify PDF Metadata using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761646/read-modify-pdf-metadata-using-itextsharp)

So, *[iText](http://itextpdf.com/) ® is a library that allows you to create and manipulate PDF documents* (from their website)

**Office** : (first link from MS stipulates that it applies to Word as well as Excel documents)

[How to: Read from and Write to Document Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4e0tda25.aspx)

[Listing properties of a word document in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047734/listing-properties-of-a-word-document-in-c-sharp)

Comment: no, FileInfo is not enough... I have to get several informations from various files (pdf, doc, xls,.. for example doc title, author and so on..)

Comment: Thanks Aybe, but I would like something quite generic for the whole files and no 3rd party tools.

Comment: Good luck on implementing those.